# Verify there is at least one table row on the page containing an arbitrary number of strings

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Easier explained with pseudocode in my opinion:

```
page.all('tr').each do |tr|
    if tr.has_text?(string1) and tr.has_text?(string2) # and so on...
        # Pass the test!
    end
end
# Else fail the test
```

Does there exist an effective way to perform this test using Capybara and Ruby/Cucumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you're trying to do

```
strings = [string1, string2, ...]
found = page.all('tr').any? do |tr|
  strings.all? { |s| tr.has_text?(s, wait: 0) }
end
expect(found).to be true
```

Comment: Had to add 'found = false' at the start, but otherwise works great. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm -- you really shouldn't have to have found=false at the beginning since it gets set to the result of `#any?` - but as long as it's working

Comment: Turns out it was because I had the found variable being assigned in a 'within' block and it needed initialized to call the expect. I just moved the expect into the 'within' and your solution works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code can be an effective way to verify if there is at least one table row on the page containing an arbitrary number of strings:

```
found = false
  page.all(:css, 'tr').each do |row|
    if row.text != ""
      found = true
    end
  end
found.should eq true
```

Hope this helps :)